# How to get svg elements by class using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, svg

I am trying to make an interactive graph out of an svg with paths for edges and circles for nodes. To find children of a node I want to be able to search edges for ids with a certain regex since the ids are all of the form: "node1_id node2_id". I've tried a number of solutions, including dollar dollar notation and placing regex directly into a find element by id, but I've had no luck. I can't find anything else that answers this and I'm pretty new to front-end dealings so I'm not sure if this might be something specific to svg or not.

```
$$('path[id^="\b10020 ([\d]+)"')
Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12

document.getElementById("\b10020 ([\d]+)")
null
```

Are probably the two most sensible attempts I've made. all edges with node1_id being 10020 in this case.

```
<path fill="none" stroke-width="1.0"
              d="M -1026.321777,958.875610 C -987.123413,912.258789 -858.400574,901.130981 -811.783752,940.329346"
              id="10020 12050" stroke-opacity="1.0" stroke="#7dcb3c"/>
```

Being an example of one such  edge that should have returned a match.

Comment: Please, show your code and what you've tried.

Comment: _dollar dollar notation_? What's that?

Comment: Also, note that if this were HTML, that `id` would be invalid. `id`s cannot contain spaces, and must start with a letter.

Comment: @Eric dollar dollar notation is the example above, with the two dollar signs. Hence, dollar dollar.

Comment: `$$` is not a _notation_. It's the name of a function provided by some javascript library. Which one are you using?

Comment: ah, my mistake. The technical term is apparently dollar-dollar syntax, but in my mind the two were equivalent. It's from prototype. http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were I doing it, I would change the markup to:

```
<path fill="none" stroke-width="1.0"
      d="M -1026.321777,958.875610 C -987.123413,912.258789 -858.400574,901.130981 -811.783752,940.329346"
      data-node-1="10020" data-node-2="12050" stroke-opacity="1.0" stroke="#7dcb3c"/>
```

Then using "single dollar notation" (aka, jQuery):

```
$('path[data-node-1="10020"]')
```

Comment: Is it possible to just add attributes to svg elements, or is data a key word?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to add new attributes, although that's not a semantically valid SVG document.

Comment: @Slater: To clarify what Sergiu is saying, it is invalid to "make up" attribute names that don't start with the `data-` prefix. It would probably still work, but it shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS selector that accepts regular expressions, not even in the next [level 4 version](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#overview). `[foo^=bar]` means "an element whose `foo` attribute value begins exactly with the string `bar`". You can do several things:

- if all you want is nodes with an ID beginning with `10020`, then you can use `$$("path[id^='10020 ']")` but this will accept IDs that don't continue with other digits only
- if you want the `10020` value to appear in the ID, regardless of the position, then use the `path[id~='10020']` selector
- if you really need to use regular expressions, then you have to walk the tree yourself and filter only the elements that you're interested in; you can optimize a bit by pre-filtering according to one of the selectors above, so that you have to check only the elements that do start with `10020`

However, there is one big problem with your usecase: **IDs may not contain spaces**, that's an invalid SVG document. You really must use another attribute than `id`, maybe `class` is better suited for you, or if there is a semantic meaning to those numbers, define your own namespace and use new attributes in that namespace.

If you use `class`, then your selectors could also become simpler: `$$("path.10020")`